# Deploying a unique application version to specific user

Tags: git, web-applications, version-control

I have an application developed in meteor js and i am using Git for version control. The app has several users but i want to add features to one particular user such that all the other users use one version of the app and one particular user uses another version of the app that has extra features.

I have used git tags to create several releases of the app. My idea of accomplishing what i ask is to have the same app in different directories like

`example.com/appv1` , `example.com/appv1-updated` but this may compicate things if more users require advanced features in their accounts.

What are some of other ways i can use to accomplish this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just have one version of the software with feature flags that can enable or disable the features, controlled by a file, or the hostname or something.

Or

2. Use branches. Add the extra features for the special customer to a special branch, and periodically merge the normal deployment branch (whatever that is for your workflow) into the special-customer-branch-with-extra-features.